# Adding javascript code instead of api endpoint for action in IFTTT service

Tags: ifttt

Does anyone know any other way to configure an action for a custom service in IFTTT. Conventionally we provide the api endpoint where IFTTT makes a POST request. Can we add some javascript logic to publish the action messages to some message queue brokers like RabbitMQ etc. ?
Any help on this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, you need the API endpoint to redirect the request to the message broker which in your case is RabbitMQ.